# Find min value for every data in matrix between cells and save the index

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, cell

I have a cell :

```
data  = 1 x 95
```

which every cell contains

```
160 x 160 double
```

I want to find the minimum value of every data(row,column) in 160 x 160 matrix between 95 cells so the answer is :

```
data = 1 x 1
min(160 x 160) double
```

Also, I want to save the index, which matrix that gives the min value for that data(row,column), the answer is like this :

```
index = 160x160
```

Is there any help? Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate the cell elements to form an ND array.

```
concatenated_data = cat(3, data{:});
[min_values, min_index] = min(concatenated_data, [], 3);
```